# Using pmap function to check whether all values in a row are positive or negative

Tags: r, purrr

I have this data frame and I would like to solely use `pmap` function to filter only rows where all values are either negative or positive. I am looking for a concise way of doing this as I thought about `c(...)` but we can only use it inside a function.
It is achievable by this code:

```
df <- tibble(x = c("a", "b", "c"), y = c(1, -1, -1), z = c(1, -1, 1), 
             p = c(1, -1, -1))

df %>%
  filter(pmap_lgl(list(y, z, p), ~ ..1 > 0 & ..2 > 0 & ..3 > 0  | 
                    ..1 < 0 & ..2 < 0 & ..3 < 0))

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  x         y     z     p
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         1     1     1
2 b        -1    -1    -1
```

So I am looking for a way that predicate applies on all values in case I had more than 3 columns that I don't want to name them or refer to them like this.

Any help would be highly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `if_all`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    filter(across(where(is.numeric), ~ . > 0)|
           if_all(where(is.numeric), ~ . < 0))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  x         y     z     p
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a         1     1     1
#2 b        -1    -1    -1
```

---

Or with `pmap` by `select`ing the `numeric` columns, check whether `all` the values are less than 0 or `|` greater than 0

```
library(purrr)
df %>%
   filter(pmap_lgl(select(., where(is.numeric)), 
              ~ all(c(...) < 0)| all(c(...)> 0)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  x         y     z     p
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a         1     1     1
#2 b        -1    -1    -1
```

Comment: Dear Arun, I already used `across` function plus `if_all` with that but I wanted to know how I can modify `pmap` to return the same result, since once you gave a thorough explanation of all possible variations. However, in that example we had a function like `which.max()` that made it easier.

Comment: Thank you very much. I used `all` but my mistake was to not include `0` in the call but outside it. Like always you came to the rescue. I can't thank you enough dear Arun.

Comment: I'm surprised if doesn't work if we replace the `across` statement with an `if_all`. I felt that it would have been more elegant to say if all are positive or if all are negative. @akrun do you know why that doesn't work?

Comment: @WilliamGram Yes earlier today we tried that with a friend on another problem. It seems in order to check for both conditions (all positive or all negative) we need to use both `if_all` with `across` or with `if_any`.

Comment: I was very confused until I realized `if_all` is new in 1.0.4.

Comment: @IanCampbell yes `if_all` and `if_any` are the latest editions since we cannot use `across` in `filter` we can use them for that purpose.