# Counting the number of row matches across a dynamic number of columns

Tags: r, tidyr, purrr

Goal: I have a table of records (for example people) with a dynamic number of variables (e.g., email, phone, birthday,..., others). I want to compare each row with every other row and sum the number of variables that match.

```
# Input
my_data <- tibble(person = c("A","B","C","E","F"),
                 email = c("A@me.com", "A@me.com", NA, NA, NA),
                 phone = c(NA, NA, NA, 801, 801),
               birthday = c("Jan1", "Jan1", NA, NA, NA))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
  person email    phone birthday
  <chr>  <chr>    <dbl> <chr>   
1 A      A@me.com    NA Jan1    
2 B      A@me.com    NA Jan1    
3 C      NA          NA NA      
4 E      NA         801 NA      
5 F      NA         801 NA
```

Using `tidyr::expand_grid`, I can get every combination of records.

```
# Munging
my_data_a <- my_data %>%
  rename_with(~str_c(., "_a"), everything())
my_data_b <- my_data %>%
  rename_with(~str_c(., "_b"), everything())
grid <- expand_grid(my_data_a, my_data_b)

# A tibble: 25 x 9
   person_a email_a  phone_a birthday_a person_b email_b  phone_b birthday_b total
   <chr>    <chr>      <dbl> <chr>      <chr>    <chr>      <dbl> <chr>      <int>
 1 A        A@me.com      NA Jan1       A        A@me.com      NA Jan1           2
 2 A        A@me.com      NA Jan1       B        A@me.com      NA Jan1           2
 3 A        A@me.com      NA Jan1       C        NA            NA NA             0
 4 A        A@me.com      NA Jan1       E        NA           801 NA             0
 5 A        A@me.com      NA Jan1       F        NA           801 NA             0
 6 B        A@me.com      NA Jan1       A        A@me.com      NA Jan1           2
 7 B        A@me.com      NA Jan1       B        A@me.com      NA Jan1           2
 8 B        A@me.com      NA Jan1       C        NA            NA NA             0
 9 B        A@me.com      NA Jan1       E        NA           801 NA             0
10 B        A@me.com      NA Jan1       F        NA           801 NA             0
# … with 15 more rows
```

Now I can compare each of the variables manually, but the issue is I will have more than email, phone, birthday.

```
grid %>%
  mutate(email_match = email_a == email_b,
         phone_match = phone_a == phone_b,
         birthday_match = birthday_a == birthday_b) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~replace_na(., 0)),
         total = email_match + phone_match + birthday_match) %>%
  select(person_a, person_b, total)

# Output
   person_a person_b total
   <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>
 1 A        A            2
 2 A        B            2
 3 A        C            0
 4 A        E            0
 5 A        F            0
 6 B        A            2
 7 B        B            2
 8 B        C            0
 9 B        E            0
10 B        F            0
# … with 15 more rows
```

This can be done by brute force in a for loop, but the data set is large:

```
# Brute force
a_col_start <- 2
a_col_end <- ncol(grid)/2
b_col_start <- a_col_end + 2
b_col_end <- ncol(grid)
for (i in 1:nrow(grid)) {
  grid[i,"total"] <- sum(grid[i,a_col_start:a_col_end] == grid[i,b_col_start:b_col_end], na.rm = TRUE)
}
grid %>%
  select(person_a, person_b, total)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pmap` function from package `purrr` for your purpose. It will make it easy to compare two vectors (in the same row) element-wise:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)


grid %>%
  mutate(total = pmap_dbl(grid, ~ sum(c(...)[str_detect(names(grid), "_a")][-1] == 
                        c(...)[str_detect(names(grid), "_b")][-1], na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  select(contains("person"), total)


# A tibble: 25 x 3
   person_a person_b total
   <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>
 1 A        A            2
 2 A        B            2
 3 A        C            0
 4 A        E            0
 5 A        F            0
 6 B        A            2
 7 B        B            2
 8 B        C            0
 9 B        E            0
10 B        F            0
# ... with 15 more rows
```

Comment: `purrr` to the rescue. I suspected a function in that package would be answer.

Comment: Yes exactly. `purrr`'s package functions are the first choices that come to my mind in col-wise and row-wise operations. In particular in your case we are dealing with 2 sets of variables in each row, I could not think of any other way. I already asked some questions regarding the applications of `pmap` thought you might be interested to take a look for future cases you might come across:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67037099/using-pmap-function-to-check-whether-all-values-in-a-row-are-positive-or-negativ
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67049561/using-pmap-with-c-part-2

Comment: Side note: this started to bog down and get slow when the input was >1M rows on my laptop. But's it's quite quick <1M rows. I'm sure there's a CS reason for that for another day. I'll trim my input down in the meantime.

Comment: Maybe a `data.table` solution will do for data sets of more than 1M row. I unfortunately have not much experience in that area. However glad to hear it will do the job for almost 1M obs.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want unique combinations you can use `combn()` to get all pairwise combinations and use this as input to `Map()` to get the sum of matches for each pair of rows.

```
people <- combn(my_data$person, 2)

match_finder <- function(x, y) {
  personx <- my_data[my_data$person == x, ]
  persony <- my_data[my_data$person == y, ]
  match_sum <- sum(personx == persony, na.rm = TRUE)
  list(person1 = as.character(x), person2 = as.character(y), match_sum = match_sum)
  }

output <- Map(match_finder, people[1, ], people[2, ], USE.NAMES = FALSE)

as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, output))

   person1 person2 match_sum
1        A       B         2
2        A       C         0
3        A       E         0
4        A       F         0
5        B       C         0
6        B       E         0
7        B       F         0
8        C       E         0
9        C       F         0
10       E       F         1
```